# Does ArcGIS Server support querying multiple layers of service in single request?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, layers, arcgis-rest-api, spatial-query

I am using ArcGIS REST services from a server-side app and parsing the JSON response. I need information from several different layers on the same service, and my queries are always for points.

Is there a way to make a single request that amalgamates results from multiple layers?

At present I can meet my requirements by making multiple requests, for example to endpoints at

- /arcgis/rest/services/foo/bar/MapServer/0/query?geometry=152.9259%2C-27.5516&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects...
- /arcgis/rest/services/foo/bar/MapServer/2/query?...as above...
- /arcgis/rest/services/foo/bar/MapServer/6/query?...as above...

My question is, am I missing some aggregated service that enables me to make a *single request* to *multiple layers* of the same service for the *same spatial query*?

Comment: I can imagine achieving some things via geoprocessing services. Can't think of other options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply - No.

You can "query", and by query, I mean do a Map Export on a mapservice to get an IMAGE of all the layers. Eg.  http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Water_Network/MapServer/export?

But to do an attribute query you must do it on each layer individually. The RESTful contract when making a query needs to be pretty well defined. I surmise that a query on the entire service would need to allow for a lot of 'what-if'. It's unlikely each layer would have the same attributes, so how could the client application expect certain attributes in a response? By doing per layer, where there is a complete layer definition, the app can get this list of attributes before making the request and know what will come back.

Comment: Thanks, good to get a clear answer and not die wondering :)